# Comparing two bsts

Tags: python, function, binary-search-tree

I would like to create a function that compares two bst together to see is they are the same.

This is what I have so far

```
def same(self,another):
    same = False
    for j in another:
        for i in self:
            if self[i] == another[j]:
                same = True

    return same
```

The way that I have to test it is this way, first.same(another) to see if they are the same.

---

This is my updated function:

```
def same(self, another):
    is_same = False
    if self == None and another == None:
        is_same = True
    if self is not None and another is not None:
        is_same = ((self._root == rs._root) and identical(self._left, rs._left) and identical(self._right, rs._right))

    return is_another
```

This is what I have come up with, but anything I test with this function im always getting a False.

Comment: how're you moving to the left and right subtree?

Comment: Well i would do it but i'm not entirely sure on how to do it,

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to give the answer straightaway but here is how you can do it.

In BST, the left node is less than or equal to root node and the right node is greater than the root node, and this property applies recursively to each node.

Therefore, for every node, you've to do the following

> 1.) if (bst1node.data==bst2node.data) check the left and right nodes:
>
> return compare(bst1node.left, bst2node.left) &&
>   compare(bst1node.right,bst2node.right);
>
> 2.) if (bst1node.data!=bst2node.data) {return false};
>
> 3.) finally, what will happen when the comparison goes beyond the leaf?
>
> if(bst1node==null && bst2node==null) return true;
>
> If one node is null, and other is not null, return false;

With these conditions, you should be able to check whether two BSTs are equal or not. That's it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know if everything works properly.